# Cancel button in mvc form

Tags: javascript, html, razor

I'm working with an mvc form that has an "edit" button, as well as a "Save" button". As of right now the "edit" button allows the user to edit the fields in the form, but I also need button that will undo any changes made and return the original information to the user. How can this be done? Thanks!

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("SaveAccount", "Location", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{ 
     some fields.....
                <button type="submit" name="EditAccount" id="EditAccount" value="Edit">Edit</button>
                <button type="submit" name="SaveAccount" id="SaveAccount" value="@Model.Location.Information">Save</button>
                <button type="submit" name="Cancel" id="Cancel" onclick="goBack()">Cancel</button>
}



 function goBack() {
    window.history.back();
};
```

This is my last attempt at the solution.

Comment: If you are on a page, and the fields are pulled from a database, and you want to stay on the page, and not save, you could do a reload instead of a back button. `window.location.reload();`

Comment: Is there a more user-friendly way to do that? I want to avoid the "to display the webpage again...." messages.

Comment: I don't know what you are talking about, `window.location.reload()` won't show a message unless you have something else setup that's not in your question, like a `beforeunload` event handler.

Answer (score 0):

Put this inside your form, and whenever you click it, the form inputs should reset it's values, however, it won't return to the original ones.

```
<input type="reset" value="Reset">
```